# Add custom header to email using MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

I'm currently using the following code to download a message, add a custom header to it and then add that message back into the mail folder:

```
using (ImapClient imap = new ImapClient())
{
    imap.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
    imap.Connect(host, port, useSSL);

    imap.Authenticate(user, password);

    IMailFolder mailFolder = imap.GetFolder(folder);
    mailFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    if (mailFolder.Count > 0)
    {
        MimeMessage message = mailFolder.GetMessage(0);

        var header = message.Headers.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Field == "X-SomeCustomHeader");
        if (header == null)
        {
            message.Headers.Add("X-SomeCustomHeader", "SomeValue");
        }

        mailFolder.SetFlags(0, MessageFlags.Deleted, true);
        mailFolder.Expunge();

        UniqueId? newUid = mailFolder.Append(message);
        mailFolder.Expunge();

        var foundMails = mailFolder.Search(SearchQuery.HeaderContains("X-SomeCustomHeader", "SomeValue"));
        if (foundMails.Count > 0)
        {
            var foundMail = mailFolder.GetMessage(new UniqueId(foundMails.First().Id));

            Console.WriteLine(foundMail.Subject);
        }

        mailFolder.Close(true);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that if I view the source of the email on the folder the header is not there and `foundMails` has a count of zero.

If I view the `message` it contains the header, so if I also do `message.WriteTo(somePath);` the header is there too.

What am I doing wrong?

This code works if I use an outlook client but when using it on a gmail one it fails.

Comment: Does the `Append` method return a uid (or null)? If it returns a uid, what happens if you do `mailFolder.GetMessage(uid.Value)`? Does *that* message have the header?

Comment: Also try getting a [ProtocolLog](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) to see if the header is included in the message when being appended to the folder.

Comment: @jstedfast It returns a uid but the message also doesn't contain the header.

Comment: @jstedfast It looks like this might be unique to gmail through my testing but not 100% on that.

Comment: A protocol log should help confirm that.

Comment: @jstedfast line 3143 `C: A00000012 APPEND folderName {237334}`, line 3178 `C: X-SomeCustomHeader: SomeValue`. Looks like it is sending it

Comment: @jstedfast line 6242 `C: A00000014 UID FETCH 372 (BODY.PEEK[])`, line 6277 `S: `. That's the empty line at the end of the headers, the custom header doesn't come back. That was from calling `MimeMessage newMessage = mailFolder.GetMessage(newUid.Value);` on the Uid returned from the `Append`.

Comment: Looks like GMail is dropping it for some reason. Perhaps it detects that it's the same message as what was there before (but misses the fact that it has a new header now?) and so just resurrects the old message? Just a guess.

Comment: @jstedfast That's what we was thinking as well, is there any way to "permanently" delete a message from GMail?

Comment: @jstedfast I've now tried deleting the message from the folder it is inside of and the special folder All but it never shows in `Trash` so I'm at a loss now

Comment: @jstedfast Doing `allMailFolder.SetFlags(allMessages[0], MessageFlags.Deleted, true);` on the `imap.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.All);` isn't deleting the mail out of the All messages folder, followed by an `Expunge` call too. Any ideas?

Comment: @jstedfast I've worked it out, you don't call delete on the message you move it to the trash folder and delete from there. It was keeping the old message like you guessed.

Comment: Yea gmail works differently from standard IMAP unless you change the settings.

Comment: @jstedfast Yeah pain in the ass didn't realise. Thanks for the help though I've got it working now.

Comment: can't you modify the existing mail? Do you have to make a new modified one and delete the existing one? I am currently trying todo something like this to mark which messages have been processed.

Comment: @Dennis We never found a way to get the header to upload without deleting the email and re uploading it. This wasn't truly a problem for us though as we were uploading to a new folder anyway. If you do find a way without this approach do post an answer here though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that calling a delete on the gmail server wasn't actually deleting the email. To get around this move the email to the Trash folder and then delete it. The following helper method gives you an idea on how to accomplish this:

```
protected void DeleteMessage(ImapClient imap, IMailFolder mailFolder, UniqueId uniqueId)
{
    if (_account.HostName.Equals("imap.gmail.com"))
    {
        IList<IMessageSummary> summaries = mailFolder.Fetch(new List<UniqueId>() { uniqueId }, MessageSummaryItems.GMailMessageId);
        if (summaries.Count != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to find the message in the mail folder.");
        }

        mailFolder.MoveTo(uniqueId, imap.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.Trash));
        mailFolder.Close(true);

        IMailFolder trashMailFolder = imap.GetFolder(SpecialFolder.Trash);
        trashMailFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

        SearchQuery query = SearchQuery.GMailMessageId(summaries[0].GMailMessageId.Value);

        IList<UniqueId> matches = trashMailFolder.Search(query);

        trashMailFolder.AddFlags(matches, MessageFlags.Deleted, true);
        trashMailFolder.Expunge(matches);

        trashMailFolder.Close(true);

        mailFolder.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
    }
    else
    {
        mailFolder.SetFlags(uniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, true);
        mailFolder.Expunge();
    }
}
```